# Login Form: Submitting Password + Saving Password in Server

Tags: php, mysql, passwords

I am a student working on a web application design. I am new to web session and security issues related to web session.

If a user creates a password using an online account-creation form, are the following steps 1. correct and 2. suffice to ensure that password is safely saved inside a server:

1. Hash password using JavaScript hashing function
2. After user clicks a form "submit" button, form data, incl. password, is sent via SSL
3. On server-side, PHP script is used to process the form data using PHP _POST
4. Save hashed password in a MySQL database (By the way, is there anything else to do at database side?)

I am particularly unsure whether step 3 and 4 are correct steps for processing and saving passwords.

Comment: Maybe you find a better answer here - https://security.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Hashing passwords on the client side isn't a good idea, since anybody can access your client-side code and view how you hash your passwords. That's dangerous especially if you are 'hasing' them using an outdated/unsecure method. A good example of this would be SHA-1, which isn't a good hash method and will produce the same hash for the same password, which isn't a good thing as attackers can 'brute force' common passwords and find identical hashes.

Instead the better method is to send the raw password via SSL and hash it via PHP using the `password_hash` and `password_verify` functions. [Read about those here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.password.php)

Once you use the `password_hash` function, it will return a unique hash everytime (even for the same password). This is what you'll want to store in your database, and when you want to 'login' or 'verify' the user's credentials, you would just run the hash saved in the database through the password_verify function which will return true or false, in which you can run your application logic based off that.

I recommend this section of 'PHP The Right Way', they have a good article on basic password hashing in PHP [Read here](https://phptherightway.com/#password_hashing)

If you are worried about passwords being stolen on it's way from the client to your server, SSL should cover that, there shouldn't be a need to hash your passwords before they get to your server, and as good practice if you have a login system on your site, you should always be using / routing data through SSL always anyway.

Also here is a snippet from that site:

```
    // Store this in your database
    $passwordHash = password_hash('secret-password', PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

    // Data recieved from login page, check the POST data against the hash in your Database
    if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $passwordHash)) {
        // Correct Password - function returned true
    } else {
        // Wrong password - function returned false
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, about your step 1: I think you shouldn't hash it at client-side, because we can not control what user would do with that password (maybe they can find out the rule of that hashed password because it's public).
I recommend to process, hash the password at server-side instead of client-side, you may use [password_hash()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function, below is 2 ways that you can create a new hash, after that you can store $hashed_password into database for further verification

```
/* this is the simple hash */
$hashed_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT); // here's the hash of the previous password
/* this is the more complexity hash */
$hashed_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array("cost" => 5)); // you may able to set the "complexity" of the hashing algorithm, it uses more CPU power but it'll be harder to crack, even though the default is already good enough
```

For password's verification, you could consider example code below:

```
if (password_verify($password, $hashed_password)) { // get the hash that was stored from db and compare it with current password
    /* Valid */
} else {
    /* Invalid */
}
```